# read a file and search for a string, if matches, return the next word in python

Tags: python

I am very new to python, I am trying to do following operation:
Read a given file ('file.txt') and search for a particular string("string") if matches, return the next word.
'file.txt' is below:

```
...
func(string=0x41004578, val=0x01)
...
...
```

So if 'string' matches in file, i want to get '0x41004578' value in return.

How to do this? I am totally blank. I am trying following

```
 file  = open('file.txt', 'r').read().find('string')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool *normally* used for things like this is grep. So, let's do the same except in Python.

```
with open('file.text', 'r') as fp:
  for line in fp:
    match = re.search('string=([^,]+)', line)
    if match:
      print match.group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams :)